# XSLT - Need help tagging text

Tags: xslt

In the following example, I need to insert an "indent" tag around the text that appears between the bulletlist end tag and the para end tag.

```
<para>Blah, blah, blah-blah, blah, blah, blah, blah<emphasis type="q">BL</emphasis>. </para>
<para>TheBlah, blah, blah-blah, blah, blah, blah, blah is created using the following schema:<bulletlist>
<li>First two letters. </li>
<li>Next four digits.</li>
<li>Next three digits.</li>
<li>Final six digits.</li>
</bulletlist>Here is the text I need to capture and place in an "indet" tag.</para>
```

How would I handle this in XSLT? I am new to the language and am getting a bit frustrated.

I also need to tag text that follows a numlist end tag, an alphalist end tag, a note end tag and a table end tag occurring in a para  with the "indent tag". Examples follow:

```
<para>Blah, blah, blah-blah, blah, blah, blah, blah<emphasis type="q">BL</emphasis>. </para>
<para>TheBlah, blah, blah-blah, blah, blah, blah, blah is created using the following schema:<numlist>
<li>First two letters. </li>
<li>Next four digits.</li>
<li>Next three digits.</li>
<li>Final six digits.</li>
</numlist>Here is the text I need to capture and place in an "indet" tag.</para>

<para>Blah, blah, blah-blah, blah, blah, blah, blah<emphasis type="q">BL</emphasis>. </para>
<para>The Blah, blah, blah-blah, blah, blah, blah, blah is created using the following schema:<numlist>
<li>First two letters. </li>
<li>Next four digits.</li>
<li>Next three digits.</li>
<li>Final six digits.</li>
</numlist>Here is the text I need to capture and place in an "indent" tag.</para>

<para>Blah, blah, blah-blah, blah, blah, blah, blah<emphasis type="q">BL</emphasis>. </para>
<para>The Blah, blah, blah-blah, blah, blah, blah, blah is created using the following schema:<note>
Blah, blah, blah, blah . . . 
</note>Here is the text I need to capture and place in an "indent" tag.</para>

<para>Blah, blah, blah-blah, blah, blah, blah, blah<emphasis type="q">BL</emphasis>. </para>
<para>The Blah, blah, blah-blah, blah, blah, blah, blah is created using the following schema:<table><tgroup cols="3" colsep="1" rowsep="3">
<colspec colname="col1" colwidth="25*"/>
<colspec colname="col2" colwidth="36*"/>
<colspec colname="col3" colwidth="39*"/>
<thead>
<row>
<entry align="center" valign="top"><emphasis type="b">Sub-status Code </emphasis></entry>
<entry align="center" valign="top"><emphasis type="b"> Sub-status Code Name</emphasis></entry>
<entry align="center" valign="top"><emphasis type="b">Description</emphasis></entry>
</row>
</thead>
<tbody>
<row>
<entry align="center" colsep="1" rowsep="1">AC</entry>
<entry colsep="1" rowsep="1">Auto Closure</entry>
<entry colsep="1" rowsep="1">Automatic closed></entry>
</row>
</tbody>
</tgroup>
</table>Here is the text I need to capture and place in an "indet" tag.</para>
```

Could anyone please offer suggestion??

I have been attempting this for several days with no success. Below appears my most recent attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()"> 
<xsl:copy> 
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/> 
</xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para-wrap/text()[following-sibling::bulletlist | alphalist | numlist | note | table]">
<indent> 
<xsl:value-of select="."/> 
</indent> 
</xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please clarify what is an example of an input, and what is the expected output (of each example, if you have several of them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean simply put a text node inside an `indent` element if it is a child of `para` and if it is an immediate following-sibling of `bulletlist`, `note`and so on? Then, the stylesheet below yields the correct output.

Since you mention the "end tag" of an element, let me clear this up for you: The way an XSLT processor sees an XML document is different from the way you see it. More precisely, the processor gets to see a *parsed* version of it, in the form of a *tree* (called XDM). In this tree, there are no tags at all, neither start nor end tags. All items are simply represented as *nodes*.

So, it is misleading to ask for an XSLT stylesheet that takes into account the end tag of an element. Your question must be interpreted as: looking for a text node that immediately follows a `bulletlist` element as its sibling.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para/text()">

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::*[1][name() = 'bulletlist' or name() = 'alphalist' or name() = 'numlist' or name() = 'table' or name() = 'note']">
                <indent>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </indent>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Applied to the following input:

**XML Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<para>Blah, blah, blah-blah, blah, blah, blah, blah<emphasis type="q">BL</emphasis>. </para>
<para>TheBlah, blah, blah-blah, blah, blah, blah, blah is created using the following schema:<bulletlist>
<li>First two letters. </li>
<li>Next four digits.</li>
<li>Next three digits.</li>
<li>Final six digits.</li>
</bulletlist>Here is the text I need to capture and place in an "indet" tag.</para>
</root>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <para>Blah, blah, blah-blah, blah, blah, blah, blah<emphasis type="q">BL</emphasis>. </para>
   <para>TheBlah, blah, blah-blah, blah, blah, blah, blah is created using the following schema:<bulletlist>
         <li>First two letters. </li>
         <li>Next four digits.</li>
         <li>Next three digits.</li>
         <li>Final six digits.</li>
      </bulletlist>
      <indent>Here is the text I need to capture and place in an "indet" tag.</indent>
   </para>
</root>
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Thanks for clearing that up for me.  I am anxious to try the code!

Comment: @TracyStahl You can try the code by simply clicking on this [link](http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiHW/1). May I ask you to consider accepting my answer if you find the answer was helpful?

Comment: Thanks for the assistance @MathiasMuller. I have been trying to implement, however, the code is not working on my full document and I am not sure why.